# Find blobs in bitmap

Tags: c#, vb.net, graph, graphics, graph-algorithm

I use [AForge.Net](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/features/blobs_processing.html) for find blobs in bitmap, my bitmap is as follows:

[image: Search for blobs in AForge.Net]

My problem is that AForge.Net detects only one blob when in fact there are two connected blobs on a thin line.

My question is there an algorithm that identifies that there are two large blobs with thin connection between them? And how I implement this algorithm in C# or VB?

Image for samples:

[image: Image for samples]

Comment: If its connected, it doesnt make it two blobs, its still one blob... If they didnt connect then yes there would be two.

Comment: You could erode the whole bitmap by a given amount (depends on your context) http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/features/morphology_filters.html before detecting blobs. You should give a pointer to your image if you want C# samples

Comment: @SimonMourier erode the whole bitmap will give an inaccurate result and change the original shape of the blobs.

Comment: Depends how you do it. Again, w/o any sample, you'll get nothing useful

Comment: Erode and dilate morphology filters would be good for removing the thin line, from that you should then be able to determine two separate blobs.

Comment: If blobs in your images be *only* connected by lines, then you can run a line detection, then remove lines and try finding blobs again. This is what we were doing for ICR image preparation, and finding signatures

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As others suggested, I would use OpenCv instead of AForge (it seems AForge has not been updated for a while plus OpenCv has lots of samples available).
With C#, I suggest the [OpenCvSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenCvSharp3-AnyCPU) nuget package. It's easy to use because the code really looks like C++ or python code, like most samples.

So, OpenCv has a blob detector, but it detects blob centers, so in your case, it seems you're more after *contours* than blobs (which is often the case).

Luckily, with OpenCv and your sample image, it just works w/o doing anything fancy (we don't even have to erode the image first), we can just use findContours, filter some glitches, and get the convexHull. Here is a sample code that demonstrates that:

```
using (var src = new Mat(filePath))
using (var gray = new Mat())
{
    using (var bw = src.CvtColor(ColorConversionCodes.BGR2GRAY)) // convert to grayscale
    {
        // invert b&w (specific to your white on black image)
        Cv2.BitwiseNot(bw, gray);
    }

    // find all contours
    var contours = gray.FindContoursAsArray(RetrievalModes.List, ContourApproximationModes.ApproxSimple);
    using (var dst = src.Clone())
    {
        foreach (var contour in contours)
        {
            // filter small contours by their area
            var area = Cv2.ContourArea(contour);
            if (area < 15 * 15) // a rect of 15x15, or whatever you see fit
                continue;

            // also filter the whole image contour (by 1% close to the real area), there may be smarter ways...
            if (Math.Abs((area - (src.Width * src.Height)) / area) < 0.01f)
                continue;

            var hull = Cv2.ConvexHull(contour);
            Cv2.Polylines(dst, new[] { hull }, true, Scalar.Red, 2);
        }

        using (new Window("src image", src))
        using (new Window("dst image", dst))
        {
            Cv2.WaitKey();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One quick solution would be to apply the opening operator
http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/features/morphology_filters.html

If the maximum thickness of the line is known in advance, one could apply the erosion operator multiple times and then apply the dilation operator the same number of times, effectively removing the thin line. This will change the shape of the 2 blobs, however.

If something  more sophisticated is required, you might want to follow the approach in this, which combines the distance transform with the watershed algorithm:
https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/db4/tutorial_py_watershed.html

Answer (score 1):

1. Try Erosion Class , it can clear up thin line in the center.

http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/90a69d73-0e5a-3e27-cc52-5864f542b53e.htm

2. Call Dilatation Class , get original size,

http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/88f713d4-a469-30d2-dc57-5ceb33210723.htm

3. and find blobs again , you will get it.

Comment: The Erosion and Dilatation will give an inaccurate result and change the original shape  of the blobs.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to use OpenCV for your project. It's more easier and faster.

Nuget:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenCvSharp3-AnyCPU/3.3.1.20171117

```
Mat im = Cv2.ImRead("blob.jpg", ImreadModes.GrayScale);
SimpleBlobDetector detector = SimpleBlobDetector.Create();
KeyPoint[] points = detector.Detect(im);
Mat result = new Mat();
Cv2.DrawKeypoints(im, points, result, Scalar.Red);
```

Comment: Can OpenCV detect two blobs in my image?

Comment: Yes it can. I think OpenCV is very powerfull.But the little line in image, connect blobs each other. First you need the solve it with Cv2.Erode, then run the BlobDetector codes

Comment: erode give an inaccurate result and change the original shape of the blobs.

Comment: [Image Segmentetion](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/db4/tutorial_py_watershed.html) Check this link. This may be what you are looking for